# Static assert of interface to class template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-assert

In a constructor template I am writing I would like to have a static assert on a the interface of a class template. A basic (non compiling) example of the situation is as follows:

```
class Baz
{

}

template<typename T>
class Bar: public Baz
{

}

template<typename T>
class Qux: public Baz
{

}

class Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    Foo(T typePar , Baz& baz)
    {
       // here I would like to assert that Baz is an interface to a class 
         specialized on T
    }
}
```

My best guess is the adding of a function to Baz, but since this cannot be templated, I would not now how I could call that at compile time.

Comment: You mean you want to check at compile-time that `Baz` is actually a reference to a `Bar<T>` or `Qux<T>`? That can't be done because the dynamic type of `baz` could be different things at runtime.

Comment: You could change `Baz&` to a template parameter and do the check then, but then you couldn't pass a `Baz` to your constructor, you'd need to cast it first.

Comment: I see what you mean. Changing it to a template parameter isn't really an option for me. So then I will just forgo this static assert

Comment: "Baz is an interface to a class specialized on T' It is very unclear what you mean by this. Baz is class with no bases or members, that's *all* what it is.